# Refact codes by Roslyn on texts without using any IDE

Tags: c#, roslyn

Now for using Roslyn for refactoring codes, we should use IDE such as VS, VS Code, Rider and ... with a click on a specific token.

I want to know Can I walk on any methods/properties/... and get refact options that available on a selected method/property/... by **text/source processing**? (**without IDE and click on it**)

I want to refact and analysis texts/sources without using an IDE I want to use an application with wizard mode and suggest refactors property by property, method by method,... (**no clicking**).

Is it possible?

Comment: Please understand what roslyn is: A compiler as a service with code analysis services. However, it does not contain actual analysers or code fixes for specific issues. Its up to you to write them. [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix) is an example.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I know Roslyn, My problem is clicking on a source and then refactoring suggestions Can I do this without IDE and clicking? I want to Roslyn refactoring in my own application by walking on codes not clicking on it.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, based on your link, for example, I want to `make constant` whole of the source without clicking on suggestion

Comment: It should be possible. After all, the analyzers and code fixes are only classes. You would need to replicate how VS walks through the file and calls the analyzers. Maybe the files in [this folder](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/DiagnosticAnalyzer) help. For example, there is a `AnalyzerExecutor` class.

Comment: U can create a solution with the required projects and analyzers. You can then check the diagnostics and apply the codefixes. This can all be done in code with the Roslyn nuget packages